# Mac act like an AirPort Express for AirTunes sharing

Tags: airport, airport-extreme, airtunes

I have a MacBook running under the TV hooked up to some speakers. I have an AirPort express running which is hooked up to some speakers. From another Mac or iPhone in the house I'd like to be able to send music to both the AirPort express and the MacBook.

Ideally I need a way of running an app on the MacBook which turns it into a real AirTunes server, any idea of an app which does this?

Answer (score 1):

[AirFoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) and [Airfoil Speakers](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/speakers.php), off the top of my head.

Comment: AirFoil and AirFoil Speakers works for sending audio from the Mac to Mac, but I can't send the audio from an iPhone to AirFoil speakers :(